# FFmpeg - write video segments with filenames containing timezone offset

Tags: ffmpeg, date-time, time-zone

I need to write an FFmpeg command that records a stream in segments of x seconds. The segments should be named using the UTC date and time (UTC+0), rather than my local PC time. Alternatively, I'm looking to add a time zone offset `+hhmm` to the file name, which currently contains my PC's date and time.

I've tried using both `z` and capital `Z` options, but they output the time zone abbreviation instead of the time zone offset.

Here's the FFmpeg command I've been working with:

```
ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:8032 -c:v libx264 -f segment -segment_time 3600 -strftime 1 mpegts %Y%m%d_%H:%M:%s%z.ts
```

Any suggestions on how to write the file name as UTC time or write the time zone offset?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, why do you want to do that? Would it be an option to simply put the system clock on UTC?

Comment: This command will run on a number of PCs, and I am not controlling their system time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strftime` option relies on system's implementation of a C function with the same name. There's nothing you can do about it in ffmpeg itself.

References:

- [rejected ffmpeg bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8415)
- [some more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187488/python-strftime-utc-offset-not-working-as-expected-in-windows), also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353015/python-time-strftime-z-is-always-zero-instead-of-timezone-offset), as to why `%z` isn't available in Windows (in Python, but reasoning is the same)

You can only achieve this through scripting, e.g. with PowerShell, as static interpolated value. For example:

```
$offset = Get-Date -Format " K"
```

stores the offset preceded with space as a variable that you can insert as `"%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%s$offset.ts"`.

Comment: Thank you. And is there a way for FFmpeg to use UTC time instead of local time?

Comment: I don't think so, ffmpeg documentation just specifies local time.